# PHP URL arguments to variable

Tags: php, parameters, arguments

I'm quite new to PHP so don't get mad if this is a simple question, I've looked about and can't figure out how to achieve this.

lots of PHP scripts will take URL arguments, such as page.php?id=3 or something similar. So I would like to store the value that id is being set to in the URL.
How do you implement this, and whats it called for future knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Thank you very much, If you make you're comment an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sides for this question , how to get the url's parameter and how to set them if you need to :

For the first one you can easily get what ever that is in the url by something like this :

```
$variable = $_GET['id'];
```

And if you want to set a different value to the url it's up to you when you set the url . for example in forms or search queries you can pass the query into the url  :

```
/something?q=searchThings
```

Answer (score 0):

when you submit data write this code in "page.php" and try it's work

```
<?php
  $id=$_GET["id"];
  echo $id;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

website.com?id=1

$var = $_GET['id'];

Impenitent similarly